# Not Defined Error when trying to use global Variables with Pandas at Module Level

Tags: python, pandas, module, global

I'm trying to make a data frame object global and i'm running into trouble and I'm not sure why. I have this across 2 files: `main.py` and `helperFunction.py`

it comes down to this format
`helperFunction.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd
def createGlobalVars(file_path):
 global my_df
 my_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
 print(my_df.head()
```

`main.py`

```
import helperFunction

def main():
 helperFunction.createGlobalVars('the_file.csv')
 print(my_df.head())
if __name__=='__main__':
 main()
```

the helper function print is correctly working:

```
    data
0   'my data'
1   'my data'
2   'my data'
3   'my data'
4   'my data'
```

but the main print is giving me
`my_df is not defined`

This violates by what I understand about global variables so I must be missing something.

Comment: does this answer your query ? [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: following that and adding `my_df=None`
to the top of the `helperFunction.py` file
and changing the import in main to `from helperFunction.py` import *

and the call to `createGlobalVars('the_file.csv')` 

now returns `None Type has no method head()` in the main

Answer (score 0):

If you mutate your global variable instead of assigning to it, things will work as expected:

```py
# helperFunction.py

import pandas as pd

my_df = []

def createGlobalVars(file_path):
    global my_df
    my_df.append(pd.read_csv(file_path))
```

```py
# main.py

from temp2 import *

def main():
    createGlobalVars('the_file.csv')
    print(my_df[0].head())


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

With the following `the_file.csv`:

```
a,b
1,2
```

Running `python main.py` outputs:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
```